# How many controller can I have/need to have?

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, controller

I'm developing a school project and I need to know more about Controllers in MVC pattern and my question is about how many controllers can I have ? I mean, if can I have one to controller to login and registration, another controller to insert, delete and update products on the application, another controller to manage users, etc. Like that.

Comment: how much you want

Answer (score 0):

You should have a controller per model, and for authentications